# Why am I not getting an output?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to filter (comments) which is survey response from CSV file so all text.
I did

```
classify[“sentiment”,comments]
```

And

```
Counts[classify[“sentiment”,comments]]
```

Which works fine

So now I want to filter my data to only show negative comments so I'm trying…

```
Select[comments,classify[“sentiment”,comments]==Negative]
```

But I'm not getting any output

Answer (score 0):

```
comments = {
   "I love this movie",
   "Of cabbages and kings",
   "My phone broke again"};

Select[comments, Classify["Sentiment", #] == "Negative" &]
```

> {"My phone broke again"}

Or calling `Classify` once on the list of comments, probably faster.

```
sentiments = Classify["Sentiment", comments];

Extract[comments, Position[sentiments, "Negative"]]
```

> {"My phone broke again"}

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did the code you provided but i keep getting a small empty box

Comment: Do you have plain text comments in a list?  as demonstrated above